# SSL read failed error on running ab command

Tags: benchmarking

When I run the following command on Mac terminal:
ab -n 1000 -c 200 "https://someurl..."
I get the following error:

```
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 1901567 $>
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/

Benchmarking www.local.lifewire.com (be patient)
SSL read failed (5) - closing connection
8364360000:error:02FFF020:system library:func(4095):Broken pipe:/AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/9e200cfa-7d96-11ed-886f-a23c4f261b56/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-3.3/ssl/tls13_legacy.c:80:
SSL handshake failed (5).
8364360000:error:02FFF020:system library:func(4095):Broken pipe:/AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/9e200cfa-7d96-11ed-886f-a23c4f261b56/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-3.3/ssl/tls13_legacy.c:80:

Test aborted after 10 failures

apr_socket_connect(): Connection reset by peer (54)
Total of 3 requests completed
```

---

I noticed that the command runs fine till -n 500 and -c 100
When I tried to run with -n 1000 -c 100 I get the following error:

```
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 1901567 $>
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/

Benchmarking www.local.url.com (be patient)
SSL handshake failed (5).
8364360000:error:02FFF020:system library:func(4095):Broken pipe:/AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/9e200cfa-7d96-11ed-886f-a23c4f261b56/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-3.3/ssl/tls13_legacy.c:80:
SSL handshake failed (5).
8364360000:error:02FFF036:system library:func(4095):Connection reset by peer:/AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/9e200cfa-7d96-11ed-886f-a23c4f261b56/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-3.3/ssl/tls13_legacy.c:43:
SSL handshake failed (5).
8364360000:error:02FFF036:system library:func(4095):Connection reset by peer:/AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/9e200cfa-7d96-11ed-886f-a23c4f261b56/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-3.3/ssl/tls13_legacy.c:43:
SSL handshake failed (5).
8364360000:error:02FFF036:system library:func(4095):Connection reset by peer:/AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/9e200cfa-7d96-11ed-886f-a23c4f261b56/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-3.3/ssl/tls13_legacy.c:43:
SSL handshake failed (5).
8364360000:error:02FFF036:system library:func(4095):Connection reset by peer:/AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/9e200cfa-7d96-11ed-886f-a23c4f261b56/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-3.3/ssl/tls13_legacy.c:43:
SSL handshake failed (5).
8364360000:error:02FFF036:system library:func(4095):Connection reset by peer:/AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/9e200cfa-7d96-11ed-886f-a23c4f261b56/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-3.3/ssl/tls13_legacy.c:43:
SSL handshake failed (5).
8364360000:error:02FFF036:system library:func(4095):Connection reset by peer:/AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/9e200cfa-7d96-11ed-886f-a23c4f261b56/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-3.3/ssl/tls13_legacy.c:43:
SSL handshake failed (5).
8364360000:error:02FFF036:system library:func(4095):Connection reset by peer:/AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/9e200cfa-7d96-11ed-886f-a23c4f261b56/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-3.3/ssl/tls13_legacy.c:43:
SSL handshake failed (5).
8364360000:error:02FFF036:system library:func(4095):Connection reset by peer:/AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/9e200cfa-7d96-11ed-886f-a23c4f261b56/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-3.3/ssl/tls13_legacy.c:43:
SSL handshake failed (5).
8364360000:error:02FFF036:system library:func(4095):Connection reset by peer:/AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/9e200cfa-7d96-11ed-886f-a23c4f261b56/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-3.3/ssl/tls13_legacy.c:43:
SSL handshake failed (5).
8364360000:error:02FFF036:system library:func(4095):Connection reset by peer:/AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/9e200cfa-7d96-11ed-886f-a23c4f261b56/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-3.3/ssl/tls13_legacy.c:43:
SSL handshake failed (5).
8364360000:error:02FFF036:system library:func(4095):Connection reset by peer:/AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/9e200cfa-7d96-11ed-886f-a23c4f261b56/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-3.3/ssl/tls13_legacy.c:43:
SSL handshake failed (5).
8364360000:error:02FFF036:system library:func(4095):Connection reset by peer:/AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/9e200cfa-7d96-11ed-886f-a23c4f261b56/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-3.3/ssl/tls13_legacy.c:43:
SSL handshake failed (5).
8364360000:error:02FFF036:system library:func(4095):Connection reset by peer:/AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/9e200cfa-7d96-11ed-886f-a23c4f261b56/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-3.3/ssl/tls13_legacy.c:43:
SSL handshake failed (5).
8364360000:error:02FFF036:system library:func(4095):Connection reset by peer:/AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/9e200cfa-7d96-11ed-886f-a23c4f261b56/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-3.3/ssl/tls13_legacy.c:43:
SSL handshake failed (5).
8364360000:error:02FFF036:system library:func(4095):Connection reset by peer:/AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/9e200cfa-7d96-11ed-886f-a23c4f261b56/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-3.3/ssl/tls13_legacy.c:43:
SSL handshake failed (5).
8364360000:error:02FFF036:system library:func(4095):Connection reset by peer:/AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/9e200cfa-7d96-11ed-886f-a23c4f261b56/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-3.3/ssl/tls13_legacy.c:43:
SSL handshake failed (5).
8364360000:error:02FFF036:system library:func(4095):Connection reset by peer:/AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/9e200cfa-7d96-11ed-886f-a23c4f261b56/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-3.3/ssl/tls13_legacy.c:43:
SSL handshake failed (5).
8364360000:error:02FFF036:system library:func(4095):Connection reset by peer:/AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/9e200cfa-7d96-11ed-886f-a23c4f261b56/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-3.3/ssl/tls13_legacy.c:43:
SSL handshake failed (5).
8364360000:error:02FFF036:system library:func(4095):Connection reset by peer:/AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/9e200cfa-7d96-11ed-886f-a23c4f261b56/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-3.3/ssl/tls13_legacy.c:43:
SSL handshake failed (5).
8364360000:error:02FFF036:system library:func(4095):Connection reset by peer:/AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/9e200cfa-7d96-11ed-886f-a23c4f261b56/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-3.3/ssl/tls13_legacy.c:43:
SSL handshake failed (5).
8364360000:error:02FFF036:system library:func(4095):Connection reset by peer:/AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/9e200cfa-7d96-11ed-886f-a23c4f261b56/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-3.3/ssl/tls13_legacy.c:43:
SSL handshake failed (5).
8364360000:error:02FFF036:system library:func(4095):Connection reset by peer:/AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/9e200cfa-7d96-11ed-886f-a23c4f261b56/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-3.3/ssl/tls13_legacy.c:43:
SSL handshake failed (5).
8364360000:error:02FFF036:system library:func(4095):Connection reset by peer:/AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/9e200cfa-7d96-11ed-886f-a23c4f261b56/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-3.3/ssl/tls13_legacy.c:43:
SSL handshake failed (5).
8364360000:error:02FFF036:system library:func(4095):Connection reset by peer:/AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/9e200cfa-7d96-11ed-886f-a23c4f261b56/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-3.3/ssl/tls13_legacy.c:43:
SSL handshake failed (5).
8364360000:error:02FFF036:system library:func(4095):Connection reset by peer:/AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/9e200cfa-7d96-11ed-886f-a23c4f261b56/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-3.3/ssl/tls13_legacy.c:43:
SSL handshake failed (5).
8364360000:error:02FFF036:system library:func(4095):Connection reset by peer:/AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/9e200cfa-7d96-11ed-886f-a23c4f261b56/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-3.3/ssl/tls13_legacy.c:43:
SSL handshake failed (5).
8364360000:error:02FFF036:system library:func(4095):Connection reset by peer:/AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/9e200cfa-7d96-11ed-886f-a23c4f261b56/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-3.3/ssl/tls13_legacy.c:43:
SSL handshake failed (5).
8364360000:error:02FFF036:system library:func(4095):Connection reset by peer:/AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/9e200cfa-7d96-11ed-886f-a23c4f261b56/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-3.3/ssl/tls13_legacy.c:43:
SSL handshake failed (5).
8364360000:error:02FFF036:system library:func(4095):Connection reset by peer:/AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/9e200cfa-7d96-11ed-886f-a23c4f261b56/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-3.3/ssl/tls13_legacy.c:43:
SSL handshake failed (5).
8364360000:error:02FFF036:system library:func(4095):Connection reset by peer:/AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/9e200cfa-7d96-11ed-886f-a23c4f261b56/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-3.3/ssl/tls13_legacy.c:43:
SSL handshake failed (5).
8364360000:error:02FFF036:system library:func(4095):Connection reset by peer:/AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/9e200cfa-7d96-11ed-886f-a23c4f261b56/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-3.3/ssl/tls13_legacy.c:43:
SSL handshake failed (5).
8364360000:error:02FFF036:system library:func(4095):Connection reset by peer:/AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/9e200cfa-7d96-11ed-886f-a23c4f261b56/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-3.3/ssl/tls13_legacy.c:43:
SSL handshake failed (5).
8364360000:error:02FFF036:system library:func(4095):Connection reset by peer:/AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/9e200cfa-7d96-11ed-886f-a23c4f261b56/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-3.3/ssl/tls13_legacy.c:43:
SSL handshake failed (5).
8364360000:error:02FFF036:system library:func(4095):Connection reset by peer:/AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/9e200cfa-7d96-11ed-886f-a23c4f261b56/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-3.3/ssl/tls13_legacy.c:43:
SSL handshake failed (5).
8364360000:error:02FFF036:system library:func(4095):Connection reset by peer:/AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/9e200cfa-7d96-11ed-886f-a23c4f261b56/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-3.3/ssl/tls13_legacy.c:43:
SSL handshake failed (5).
8364360000:error:02FFF036:system library:func(4095):Connection reset by peer:/AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/9e200cfa-7d96-11ed-886f-a23c4f261b56/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-3.3/ssl/tls13_legacy.c:43:
SSL handshake failed (5).
8364360000:error:02FFF036:system library:func(4095):Connection reset by peer:/AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/9e200cfa-7d96-11ed-886f-a23c4f261b56/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-3.3/ssl/tls13_legacy.c:43:
SSL handshake failed (5).
8364360000:error:02FFF036:system library:func(4095):Connection reset by peer:/AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/9e200cfa-7d96-11ed-886f-a23c4f261b56/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-3.3/ssl/tls13_legacy.c:43:
SSL handshake failed (5).
8364360000:error:02FFF036:system library:func(4095):Connection reset by peer:/AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/9e200cfa-7d96-11ed-886f-a23c4f261b56/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-3.3/ssl/tls13_legacy.c:43:
SSL handshake failed (5).
8364360000:error:02FFF036:system library:func(4095):Connection reset by peer:/AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/9e200cfa-7d96-11ed-886f-a23c4f261b56/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-3.3/ssl/tls13_legacy.c:43:
SSL handshake failed (5).
8364360000:error:02FFF036:system library:func(4095):Connection reset by peer:/AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/9e200cfa-7d96-11ed-886f-a23c4f261b56/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-3.3/ssl/tls13_legacy.c:43:
Completed 100 requests

Test aborted after 10 failures

apr_socket_connect(): Connection reset by peer (54)
Total of 174 requests completed
```

What could be the reason for this?  It's pretty random actually. I tried running ab -n 500 -c 100 URL again when the last one finished then I got this message:

```
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 1901567 $>
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/

Benchmarking www.local.url.com (be patient)
SSL handshake failed (5).
8364360000:error:02FFF020:system library:func(4095):Broken pipe:/AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/9e200cfa-7d96-11ed-886f-a23c4f261b56/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-3.3/ssl/tls13_legacy.c:80:

Test aborted after 10 failures

apr_socket_connect(): Connection reset by peer (54)
Total of 2 requests completed
```

I am load testing a local url